# To check whether a function is unbounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Show that $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $f(x)=2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2}, ~~x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is unbounded on every neighbourhood of $0$.

Attempt:
$|f(x)|=|2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2}|\leq |2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}|+|\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2}|\leq 2+|\frac{2}{x}|$. At the neighbourhood 
 of $x=0$, $\frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded, so $f(x)$ cannot be written as $|f(x)|\leq K$ for some positive $K$. Thus $f(x)$ is unbounded.

Is this proof right?

Comment: This just shows that your function is less than an unbounded function. You need to show that it is *greater than* an unbounded function (at certain points).

Comment: @Clayton Edited, please see

Comment: It still is not correct. You must show that given any $N>0$, you can find an $x$ as close to $0$ as one pleases such that $|f(x)|>N$. It *does* involve the $1/x$, but you must be careful.

Comment: @Clayton Ok. Thanks. Would you please elaborate how to show $|f(x)|>N$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k\pi}}$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}, k > 0$.

Then $$f \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k\pi}} \right)=-2\sqrt{2k\pi}$$

As $k\to \infty, x_k \to 0, |f(x_k)| = 2\sqrt{2k\pi}\to \infty$.